# Principal Component Analysis converts 3d array to 1d array using Python

Tags: python, arrays, pca

I have the following input data `[-5, 10,2], [-2, -3,3], [-4, -9,1], [7, 11,-3], [12, 6,-1], [13, 4,5]` on hand and would like to use PCA to convert from 3D array to 1D array. I typed with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
input = np.array([[-5, 10,2], [-2, -3,3], [-4, -9,1], [7, 11,-3], [12, 6,-1], [13, 4,5]]) 
mean_x = np.mean(input[0,:])
mean_y = np.mean(input[1,:])
mean_z = np.mean(input[2,:])
scaled_vector = np.array([input[0,:]-[mean_x],input[1,:]-[mean_y],input[2,:]-[mean_z]])
data=np.vstack((scaled_vector)).T
scatter_matrix=np.dot(np.transpose(data),data)
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(scatter_matrix)
eig_pairs = [(np.abs(eig_val[i]), eig_vec[:,i]) for i in range(len(eig_val))]
eig_pairs.sort(reverse=True)
feature=eig_pairs[0][1][2]
new_data_reduced=np.dot(data,np.transpose(feature))
print(new_data_reduced)
```

I also use the `sklearn.decomposition import PCA` to do as verification.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.array([[-5, 10,2], [-2, -3,3], [-4, -9,1], [7, 11,-3], [12, 6,-1], [13, 4,5]]) 
pca = PCA(n_components=1)
pca.componrnt = True
newX = pca.fit_transform(X)
print (newX)
```

The results from `sklearn` is

```
[[  1.81922968]
 [  8.34080915]
 [ 13.64517202]
 [ -8.17114609]
 [ -8.37254693]
 [ -7.26151783]]
```

I am not sure if this results is correct or not. However, when I use my own PCA, I find that the results are extremely different. Therefore, how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you subtract the mean along rows instead of column. Then, after computing the eigenvectors, you make several steps that are unnecessary for PCA. A reduced version of your code is:

```
    import numpy as np
    input = np.array([[-5, 10,2], [-2, -3,3], [-4, -9,1], 
                      [7, 11,-3], [12, 6,-1], [13, 4,5]])
    data = input - np.mean(input, axis=0)
    scatter_matrix = np.dot(data, data.T)
    eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(scatter_matrix)
    new_reduced_data = np.sqrt(eig_val[0]) * eig_vec.T[0].reshape(-1,1)
    print(new_reduced_data)
```

which seems to give the correct result.